# suspence in vue 3 removes some buttons

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

I'm usually not a vue developer (or frontend) but everyone else is in their well deserved holidays and I want to finish this last ticket before I leave myself...

The following code blog displays A Table with data and two Buttons on each row when everything is sycnron

```
      <NTable
        :fields="fields"
        :items="lkwQuellen"
        :filters="filters"
        :busy="isLoading"
        defaultSortKey="defaultSort"
        defaultSort="desc"
      >
        <template #cell-actions="{ item }">
          <div v-if="!isLoading" class="is-flex">
            <NButton
              size="small"
              variant="secondary"
              icon="far fa-address-book"
              class="mr-2"
              @click="showKontakte(item as ILkwQuelle)"
            >
            </NButton>
            <router-link :to="ROUTES.getLkwParkplatzEditorRoute(item.id)">
              <NButton size="small" icon="fa-edit"></NButton>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </template>
      </NTable>
```

Now I need to change it so that NTable loads in some user Preferences with a backend-call. In Order to make the table wait for this data, I changed it to:

```
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <NTable
        :fields="fields"
        :items="lkwQuellen"
        :filters="filters"
        :busy="isLoading"
        defaultSortKey="defaultSort"
        defaultSort="desc"
      >
        <template #cell-actions="{ item }">
          <div class="is-flex">
            <NButton
              size="small"
              variant="secondary"
              icon="far fa-address-book"
              class="mr-2"
              @click="showKontakte(item as ILkwQuelle)"
            >
            </NButton>
            <router-link :to="ROUTES.getLkwParkplatzEditorRoute(item.id)">
              <NButton size="small" icon="fa-edit"></NButton>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </template>
      </NTable>
    </template>
    <template #fallback> Loading </template>
  </Suspense>
```

Now the table only loads in after the user-Preferences are retrieved and applied (manly which columns should be displayed).

However, for some reason, the two Buttons aren't shown anymore. I have to guesses as to why:

1. The two functions they relay on are also async, but only after clicking on the button. Suspense doesn't recognize that and waits for the action to finish?
2. The NButton are loaded in but suspense is still waiting for NTable, so the buttons aren't added to the NTable after it's loaded in.
   Either way, I'm stumped about how to change it.

I did try to add a v-if="!isLoading" to the div and added a @resolve to the suspense that changed the isLoading state but that changed nothing.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are making an async call that returns you which fields have to be shown right ? How is this implemented in the NTable component ? Is the call being made in the NTable component or in the component that has the Suspense ?

Comment: please add minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Billuc
The data is called in the component that has the suspense and filled in after it is availabe but the NTable component is created bevor that, for that it has to be desided which Coloums are shows, this async data is loaded in the NTable component itself.

Comment: @Timmy my guess is that you should make the component inside the suspense tag call the async method. If you look in the doc (https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html), the component **inside** the suspense are considered suspendible (async). I agree that it might not solve the problem, but since we don't have more details or a repro, I can only guess